# Flask migrate doesn't detect models.py

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm attempting to run `flask migrate db` in my working directory, and it does not use the model I defined in models.py
Here's the code.

## models.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")

from Talks2 import db

class Talk(db.Model):
    presenter = db.Column(db.Text())
    talkType = db.Column(db.Text())
    desc = db.Column(db.Text(), primary_key=True)
    link = db.Column(db.Text())
    time = db.Column(db.Integer())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Presenter: {}\nType: {}\nDescription:\n{}\nLink:  {}".format(self.presenter,self.talkType,self.desc,self.link)
```

## routes.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")

from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from Talks2 import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app,db)

from Talks2 import models

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/add", methods=["POST"])
def add():
    person = request.form["presenter"]
    ttype = request.form["type"]
    desc = request.form["desc"]
    link = request.form["link"]
    print(person, file=sys.stderr)
    print(ttype, file=sys.stderr)
    print(desc, file=sys.stderr)
    print(link, file=sys.stderr)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

What do I need to change for it to correctly generate the script?

Comment: The command is `flask db migrate` not `flask migrate db`. If that is not the issue, it would help to see the output of the actual command as well as the generated version file.

Answer (score -1):

You are importing `db` from `Talks2.py` in `models.py` file and again in `routes.py` declaring again.

You haven't shared the code of `Talks2.py` file. What I am suspecting is you are declaring `app` and `db` object multiple times and replacing it with others.

Just do import in the proper way and your model will be detected by the flask.

The simplest solution is to declare `app` & `db` in `Talks2.py`, then import both in `models.py` and then from `models.py` import `app` & `db` in `routes.py`. This will resolve your problem.

Also, it should be `flask db migrate` instead of `flask migrate db`.

For more information refer to these commands:

To create a migration repository:

```
flask db init
```

To Generate Migration Script (Make sure to reviewed and edited, as Alembic currently does not detect every change you make to your models)

```
flask db migrate
```

To apply the migration to the database

```
flask db upgrade
```

To see all the commands that are available run this command:

```
flask db --help
```

For more info refer [this official doc](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Let me know if this didn't help.